# Is Stack Overflow controlled by an old guard that puts off new users from contributing?

Tags: discussion, reputation, new-users, users

Perhaps I'm being a devil's advocate, but as a new user - but with a good level of knowledge - there have been a couple of instances I've seen over the last few weeks, where a user (with high(ish) reputation) has basically told me or another user that an answer was not good enough, but they didn't try to improve or help the understanding the author.

Surely the point of Stack Overflow is that **all** users are able to improve and expand their knowledge, and not be looked down on by a small number of self-appointed *senior* users who are, in my view, too full of their own self-importance.

If you have seen this yourself, you know what I mean, if you haven't... It's probably you!

:D

Comment: Are we still closing as duplicate of "Why is SO so negative as of late"?

Comment: What have I done? This is it, I remove my age from my profile...

Comment: @rene, you are #8 most close-vote reviewer. Clearly you have committed terrible crimes.

Comment: @gunr2171 Ah, yeah, that is true...guilty as charged

Comment: @gunr2171 Could well fit, I'm doing so now :P ...

Comment: Care to be more specific? Your last few answers look like they have been reasonably well received.

Comment: I think comments are fairly impartial as they don't show the user rep upfront (there's a tooltip with this info if we hover the user's name). Please, show some (anonyminized) examples.

Comment: I simply don't see what you are referring to in your question here. You got some very helpful comments.

Comment: I had one problem myself, but the point was more general. Give me a moment and I'll find some better examples.

Comment: If you find other examples of people really being *rude*, they should be flagged for moderators to look into, of course. But just to emphasize the point: I don't see anything remotely negative in the comments you've gotten from people with any measurable reputation. Just very helpful comments. (Moderators can see deleted comments too, btw)

Comment: Actually one of the comments I got was deleted after someone else flagged it. Finding a couple of examples for you from other users.

Comment: Yep.  Works wonderfully.

Comment: I'm going to be honest and say that I was being far too negative in my original question. Rather than being non-constructive, the comments I had been concerned about were more sharp and perhaps not pointing users to good example answers.

Comment: I am a pragmatic and active learner, so being thrown a lot of theory makes me think that the poster believes I should know better. That's not going to change I suspect!

Comment: This brings up a question of etiquette. If I was to down-vote this and (assuming the chance re-appears) vote to close simply to deny our august OP the opportunity to contribute, would it be required to cackle madly while I did it? If not required, is it allowed?

Comment: Not that I have any reason for asking, of course...

Comment: I was a new user a few months ago, and no one was rude to me. [Am pretty active on MSO  too](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=participation), but haven't faced any rudeness yet. [I contribute answers in same posts as hig rep users](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20838011/2982225), [still no rudeness](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20779608/2982225). So I don't identify with your question.

Comment: Whats the point of down voting again?

Answer (score 38):

Well, **I hope so!** That's one of the advantages of having this tiered reputation/privilege system: it's much harder for a group of new users to show up and ride roughshod over the site without the approval of the existing core membership. Giving the folks who've invested their time and energy into building this place a bit of say in which direction it heads is only fair, really.

But that's not really what you're asking, is it? Perhaps you feel that senior members are blocking new folks from participating in a way that *they themselves actively participate?* A sort of "earn your BS" system that institutionalizes double-standards?

If so, that's something very different, and you should raise a discussion addressing *that specifically*. Preferably with concrete examples of it happening.